# Automating the scheduletable of jobs

Tags: sql

There is a table where we had jobnames and there tsrat time stored I want to run a script which will run and check if any jobdidnot start by its scheduletime.

Actually basically I want to create a script which will call my sql query

For example table name is SCHEDULE..column JOBNAME and COLUMN SCHEDULE_TIME
and lets take one example as JObname X should start by 10:30 AM

Thank you ....Please help

Comment: What is the name of the table that holds the actual time each job ran? And on what field is that time?

Comment: Tablename is schedule columns are jobname and schedule_time

Comment: I know that but what table holds the times that jobs are ACTUALLY run? What table's field holds the date/time with which you want to compare the scheduled time?

Comment: example table holds the in column schedule_time which has combination of date and what time it will run

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table that holds what jobs were run and when is called "JOBLOG" and the actual time each job is run is stored in a column called "ACTUAL_TIME" on that table, you would run something like the following:

This will show jobs that started after they were scheduled, or jobs that were scheduled to run 10 or more minutes ago, but which have not yet started (in the latter case, the third column will be null)

```
select s.jobname, s.schedule_time, l.actual_time
  from schedule s
  left join joblog l
    on s.jobname = l.jobname
 where l.actual_time > s.schedule_time
    or (l.actual_time is null
   and (sysdate - s.schedule_time) * 24 * 60 >= 10)
```

Comment: this is correct but we would get the actual_time stored only when job runs but what we want is we should know prior hand after 10 mins only when the job didnot run

Comment: @user3867974 then you will have to compare schedule_time with the current time as well, and show jobs that have not yet run but which were scheduled to run 10 or X minutes ago. However different databases have different means of showing the current time (ie. Oracle has sysdate, mysql has current_date) can you please let us know what database you are using?

Comment: oracle atabase we are using

Comment: Also what is the data type of the "schedule_time" field? Is it a timestamp, datetime, etc?

Comment: @user3867974 try the example in my edit, that should calculate the difference between the current time and the scheduled time. If the scheduled time is stored as a timestamp rather than a date (fractional seconds is the difference, in Oracle), you would replace sysdate with systimestamp

Comment: Thank you let me try and come back